# Go: add backslash in front of '|' characters

Tags: go

I'm trying to replace all the instances of | in a string with \| but when
I try to do:

```
strings.Replace(f, "|". '\|', -1)
```

I get: expected selector or type assertion, found 'CHAR' ' \| ' error.

Comment: Single quotes are for [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals). They may only contain one rune. If you use double quotes then you need to escape the escape character (i.e. `"\\|"`). If you do not have the need for escaping stuff then you can use backticks (`\`\|\``). Inside backticks nothing has special meaning (except backticks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

```
strings.Replace(f ,"|", `\|`, -1)
```

example:

http://play.golang.org/p/EQFR2EX5Bi